# Missing object in blender 2.80

Tags: rendering, objects, particles

I'm following the donut tutorial. When I see the viewport the icing is there

[image]

However, after rendering it is missing

[image]

I already check all the cameras on ray visiblity

Answer (score 1):

You've likely disabled *Show Emitter* in the particle settings. The checkbox needs to be selected otherwise the particle emitter will not be visible in your render.

[image: Particle Settings]

Comment: thank you very much. Now i can continue the tutorial

Comment: @YulianDwi Great! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.